# Wrap image around canvas in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, image, graphics, wpf-controls

[image]

How can I wrap an image around the canvas like this? The obvious way I can think of is to duplicate the image, and offset by the width/height of the image in the opposite direction. Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fill a Rectangle with an ImageBrush with this image, and set its `TileMode` and `Viewport` properties as needed.

For example:

```
<Rectangle Width="128" Height="128">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images\Tile.png" TileMode="Tile"
                    ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="64,64,128,128"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

The above XAML creates the following output:

[image]

from this source image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**No**. There is no other way around. You will have to draw all images. Because a control doesn't split up.

You can calculate and then generate Image boxes to show no. of images based on offset.

Comment: Is there a simple way to check if an image is touching the border? Those that are will be duplicated and translated appropriately. Or will I have to duplicate every single image, even those that don't touch the edges?

Comment: No you can check for the border image. get the size of image, and subtract it from the size of form. Its a simple logic. Have a loot at this answer too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303726/wpf-image-panning-constraints