# WPF Image panning limit

Tags: wpf

I am using the below code to allow the user to pan two images. I want to limit the panning so the image stops at the beginning of the viewbox (so there is never any white space).

I have looked at the other answer I could find ([WPF Image Panning Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303726/wpf-image-panning-constraints)), but I'm not sure how to adapt it to my code. I've tried checking if the image bounds are within the grid (which is the images parent), and they aren't, so no panning can happen.

Not sure if the problem is with the way I'm panning, I use a grid (rather than a border) as I need to pan two images so they appear as one long image. The viewbox is there because without it, the area of the images off the screen weren't painted when moved onto the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RicohToPP_WPF.PanImageControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RicohToPP_WPF"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1">
<Grid>
    <Viewbox x:Name="viewBox1" Stretch="UniformToFill" >
        <Grid x:Name="grid">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="image1" Stretch="UniformToFill" ClipToBounds="False" Grid.Column="0" MouseLeftButtonDown="image1_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="image1_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="image1_MouseMove" Cursor="Cross"/>
            <Image x:Name="image2" Stretch="UniformToFill" ClipToBounds="False" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-2,0,0,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="image2_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="image2_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="image2_MouseMove" Cursor="Cross" />
        </Grid>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

```
private void RecalculatePositions(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var tt1 = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)this.image1.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
    var tt2 = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)this.image2.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
    Vector vector = this._startPoint - e.GetPosition(this.grid);

    double newX = this._originPoint.X - vector.X;
    double newY = this._originPoint.Y - vector.Y;

    if (newX <= 0)
    {
        tt1.X = newX;
        tt2.X = newX;
    }

    if (newY <= 0)
    {
        tt1.Y = newY;
        tt2.Y = newY;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"couldn't get it to work"* is not a sufficient problem description. You should explain exactly what you've tried and how your attempt failed. You appear to be using a Viewbox, while the other question has an Image with RenderTransform in a Border element. A significantly different approach at least.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added more information, regarding what I've tried.  And added the xaml.